# Removing the warning message that pops up when using an at command

Tags: command-line, echo, at

I was using an `at` command in my bash profile to echo the time of day at every hour to remind me of the time but now when I open up the command line it flashes a lot of annoying warning like these:

```
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 241 at Thu Sep  1 00:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 242 at Thu Sep  1 01:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 243 at Thu Sep  1 02:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 244 at Thu Sep  1 03:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 245 at Thu Sep  1 04:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 246 at Thu Sep  1 05:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 247 at Thu Sep  1 06:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 248 at Thu Sep  1 07:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 249 at Thu Sep  1 08:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 250 at Thu Sep  1 09:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 251 at Wed Aug 31 10:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 252 at Wed Aug 31 11:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 253 at Wed Aug 31 12:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 254 at Wed Aug 31 13:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 255 at Wed Aug 31 14:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 256 at Wed Aug 31 15:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 257 at Wed Aug 31 16:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 258 at Wed Aug 31 17:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 259 at Wed Aug 31 18:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 260 at Wed Aug 31 19:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 261 at Wed Aug 31 20:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 262 at Wed Aug 31 21:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 263 at Wed Aug 31 22:00:00 2016
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
job 264 at Wed Aug 31 23:00:00 2016
```

The command I am trying to run is example:

```
echo "midnight" | at 00:00
```

How can I remove these warnings?

Notes: It is not like the question; "Why does `at` warn me that commands will be executed using /bin/sh? What if I want a different shell?" because, I don't want know why I want to know how to get rid of warning and I don't want to know anything anything about the shell.

Comment: FYI: Sounds like you want cron—that's the normal way to run a command every hour.

Comment: Except for that the output I want is different every hour. Example:

Comment: midnight, 7 o'clock, ect.

Comment: I have had one answer and it worked so unless you have a better answer or explanation of why that worked then please stop commenting.

Comment: also please stop marking this as a duplicate because I have looked at the other question and it asking how to use a different shell to get rid of the warning message where as I just want to change the command so it doesn't show the warning and the answer I got that worked was not on the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo "midnight" | at 00:00 2>/dev/null`